# xtext, content assist unwanted suggestions

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend

I have a Script language with content assist. but this content assists shows same unwanted suggestions.

[image]

in this case I don't want the `Value - ID` and the `.` to be shown. 
the other suggestions are correct.

this my method to implement the content assist.

```
public override completeAttributeRef_AttributeRef(EObject model, Assignment assignment, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {

                val classID = (model as AttributeRef).cosem.classid 
                val CosemClasseManager = new CosemClasses()
                var proposal = CosemClasseManager.getAttributeString(classID)

                for (String s : proposal) {
                acceptor.accept(createCompletionProposal(s, s, null , context))}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ProposalProvider` you can override the following three methods and have them return `false`:

```
@Override
protected boolean doCreateIntProposals() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean doCreateStringProposals() {
    return false;
}

@Override   
protected boolean doCreateIdProposals() {
    return false;
}
```

Those are responsible for determining whether the default proposals for `INT`, `STRING` and `ID` proposals should be shown.